# Identify GSM Carrier of SIM Card Inserted into a Linux Host

Tags: linux, networking, scripting, networkmanager, gsm

The SIM card used in each Linux gateway for the GSM connection will vary from location to location due to signal coverage by different GSM carrier networks.

But in order to automate setting the APN when configuring a GSM connection, it's necessary to first determine the GSM carrier of a SIM inserted into the gateway.

How can the carrier be identified from the CLI using ***NetworkManager***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To identify the GSM carrier of an inserted SIM card into a Linux host:

```
mmcli -m 0|grep "operator name"|cut -d ':' -f2|xargs
```

With this information the APN for the GSM connection can now be set correctly.